# Metric Space (Elementary Analysis)

Tags: metric-spaces

Does there exist any continuous bijection from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$? Explain why.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There’s even a homeomorphism: it’s a result due to Sierpiński that all countable metric spaces without isolated points are homeomorphic. This is not entirely trivial to prove, however.

**Added:** [This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1008) at arXiv.org gives one elementary proof of Sierpiński’s result.

Answer (score -3):

yes there is a continuous bijection function $f:\mathbb{Q}\mapsto\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This does seem to provide an answer to the question, but it could use a bit more explanation. See Brian Scott's answer for example.

Comment: please explain why?